# Multiple UITextFields added programmatically , only one can be edited

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, interaction

I have a problem adding multiple UITextFields in a UIView, they are added correctly but it happens that the user can only edit the first of them ( touching it so the keyboard appears), i have set the delegate to self, and implemented the method textFieldDidBeginEditing. Sadly only the first one reacts triggers this methods, the others seem to be "untouchable".

Have you experienced this before?

```
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++){


    CGRect textFieldNewFrame = CGRectMake(200,60 + 34*i,72,30);        
    fields[i] = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldNewFrame];
    [fields[i] setTag:i];
    [fields[i] setText:@"0"];
    [fields[i] setFont:appFont];
    [fields[i] setTextColor:appColor];
    [fields[i] setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_field_off.png"]];
    [fields[i] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];       
    [fields[i] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
    [fields[i] setDelegate:self];
    [fields[i] setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [listView addSubview:fields[i]];

    verticalOffset += 34;
}


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;{
    NSLog(@"TextField touched");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check frame for `listView`, if its height < 90 then it is a true behaviour.

Comment: When you say "added correctly", do they appear on screen in the right place? Try `setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]` to see better what's going on. Also, how are you declaring `fields`?

Comment: ok beryllium was right, i was not modifying the frame of listView, so the touches were only being transmitted to the first UITextField which happened to be inside listViews frame. making:

[listView setFrame:CGRectMake(listView.frame.origin.x, listView.frame.origin.y, 320, verticalOffset + 40)];

did it! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, it's just an object oriented answer, should work, have worked for me many times.

```
NSMutableArray *fields=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0;i<N;i++){       
CGRect textFieldNewFrame = CGRectMake(200,60 + 34*i,72,30);             
[fields  addObject:[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldNewFrame]];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setTag:i];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setText:@"0"];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setFont:appFont];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setTextColor:appColor];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_field_off.png"]];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];            
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setDelegate:self];     
[[fields objectAtIndex:i] setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];     
[listView addSubview:[fields objectAtIndex:i]];
verticalOffset += 34; }
```